Proving the equivalence of two fields which are quotients of polynomial rings
Apologies if this question has been asked in some form before, but I wasn't able to find it.
Isomorphic quotient rings of polynomial rings over field is a similar question but it asks for the equivalence of quotient rings, rather than just fields.
Suppose that I want to construct $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + 1)$. Since $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible, we're modding out by a maximal ideal and this should be a field; moreover, this field should be of the form $\mathbb{R}[a]$ where a satisfies the equation $a^2 + 1 = 0$. We know the punchline; this is the field $\mathbb{C}$, which alternately we could express as $\mathbb{R}[i]$, and a = i here.
But suppose further that I wanted to construct, say, $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + 4)$. Well, since we're familiar with $\mathbb{C}$, it's clear that the element that we're adjoining to $\mathbb{R}$ is going to be $2i$, which functionally gives us the same field. But how can we see that these two fields are isomorphic from a description of the polynomials?
Moreover, how can you do this with a polynomial like, say, $x^2 + 2x + 4$, where the new element adjoined via the formal construction above is not a simple multiple of $i$?
Finally, are there any methods which generalize to all field extensions?
I am aware of the existence of a proof that all finite fields are isomorphic; I'm not sure if that has any relevance here.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Quadratic extensions a relatively easy to handle. It is a bit less obvious that $\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3-2\rangle$ and $\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3-3x^2-3x-1\rangle$ are isomorphic. The latter cubic has $1+\root3\of2+\root3\of4$ as one of its zeros.

Suppose we want to show that $\mathbb{R}[X]/\langle f(X)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[X]/\langle X^2 +1\rangle=\mathbb{C}$, where $f(X)=X^2+2bX+c$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[X]$.
Consider the (evaluation) map $\epsilon:\mathbb{R}[X]\to\mathbb{C}$ given by  $\epsilon: g(X)\mapsto g(-b+i\sqrt{c-b^2}$, where $i$ denotes as usual the coset $X+\langle X^2+1\rangle$ in $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}[X]/\langle X^2 +1\rangle$.
It is straightforward to compute that the kernel of $\epsilon$ is $\langle f(X)\rangle$ and so $\epsilon$ induces the isomorphism  $\mathbb{R}[X]/\langle f(X)\rangle\simeq \mathbb{R}[X]/\langle X^2 +1\rangle$ that we seek.

This is not a complete characterization, but it's a pretty solid special case:
$F[x]/p(x)$ and $F[x]/q(x)$ are isomorphic if there exists a linear polynomial $\ell(x)$ and a constant $\lambda\in F^\times$ such that $p(x)=\lambda q(\ell(x))$. With the examples from the OP where $F=\Bbb R$:

$x^2+1 = \frac14\bigl( \ell(x)^2+4 \bigr)$ where $\ell(x)=2x$
$x^2+2x+4 = 3\bigl( \ell(x)^2+1 \bigr)$ where $\ell(x) = \frac1{\sqrt3}(x+1)$

Proof sketch: the map from $F[x]/p(x)$ to $F[x]/q(x)$ that sends $x$ to $\ell(x)$ is a field isomorphism.
